# Simulate PC keyboard on Mac

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard

I have a virtual machine with OS X on a Windows PC. Is there a utility software to install on OS X that will simulate the PC keyboard layout, especially for typing `{`, `}`, `[`, `@`. etc?

Comment: Had a look at the DoubleCommand utility?

Comment: yes , but it does not seem to work :(

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I mean, I don't know what you mean by simulating { and }, since PC and Mac keyboards both have those, and in the same positions even. Option, Command and Window keys on the other hand...

Comment: actually, the problem is when I type "{" on my pc keyboard, I get the "'" character on the mac, what I am looking for is a utility for mac OS that would remap the keyboard so I could type just like a PC keyBoard

Comment: I found another solution : http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele     to create a custom keyboard layout and place it in /Library/Keyboard Layouts

Comment: It seems to be an issue choosing the correct keyboard layout, rather than simulating anything cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, make sure you're using a correct keyboard layout. Unless you know what you're doing, and actually use languages other than English, select "U.S. English" and not International PC or similar.

Secondly, I suggest [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). It has million of different tweaks and adjustments that you can enable to customize your keyboard, some of them make a life with PC keyboard on a Mac bearable.

[image]

Comment: You can also add your own remappings by creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en). The [predefined mappings](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml) and [keycode constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data) are listed in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) tool that lets you create custom keyboard layouts for MAC OS X , it worked fine for me